# Propiedad con condicion C#

Tags: c#, .net, props

Hola amigos tengo una duda, como puedo poner una condicion dentro de un propedad?? Quiero hacer esto en base a otra propiedad del mismo modelo, aqui mi ejemplo

```
public string Last4 { get; set; }
    public string MY { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public MopType CardIcon { get; set; }
    public string SelectedString {
    get;
     // aqui quiero algo como
    if(IsSelected){ set = "Selecionado"}
    else{ set = " " }
    }
```

se me ocurrio esto, pero mi **_selectedString** siempre llega **null**

```
private string _selectedString;
    public string SelectedString {
        get { return _selectedString; }
        set {
            if (IsSelected)
            {
                _selectedString = "Selecionado";
            }
            else
            {
                //DEFAULT Value. 
                _selectedString = " ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vos queres que al cambiar la propiedad IsSelected, entonces se cambie el codigo de la propiedad SelectedString. Bueno, entonces lo que tenes que haces es controlar esa propiedad y cambiar el texto en la otra dependiendo de esa propiedad.

Sencillamente, tu propiedad donde tenemos que trabajar es IsSelected.

```
private bool isselected;
public string SelectedString {get; set;}
public bool IsSelected{
    get { return isselected; }
    set {
        //value es el parametro implicito que recibe la propiedad
        //es el nuevo valor a poner en la variable
        isselected = value;
        if (isselected)
        {
            SelectedString = "Selecionado";
        }
        else
        {
            //DEFAULT Value. 
            SelectedString = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción muy sencilla es simplemente devolver el valor de `SelectedString` en función del de `IsSelected`:

```
public string SelectedString {
    get 
    {
        if (IsSelected) 
        {
             return "Seleccionado";
        }
        else
        {
             return " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

y porque no usas los operadores ternarios, planteando tu caso, seria mas o menos asi

```
public string Last4 { get; set; }
public string MY { get; set; }
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
public MopType CardIcon { get; set; }
public string SelectedString { get; set; }

if (IsSelected)
{
 //si _selectedString es null tomar el segundo mensaje("tu dato opcional")
_selectedString = "Selecionado" ?? "tu dato opcional";
}
```

Comment: Este pedazo de codigo, donde iria? no queda clara tu respuesta...

Comment: @gbianchi al usar un operador temario das otra opción de null, el chico dice que si la propiedad es null, ejemplo si recibes null y al usar un operador ternario, le das otro valor, cambias el valor de null por otro de tu preferencia

Comment: Eso no es lo que te pregunte.. te pregunte, donde escribirias ese pedazo de codigo... dentro de una propiedad? porque no queda claro en tu respuesta donde se escribe ese pedazo de codigo...

Comment: No se que te refieres con escribir ese pedazo de código, el chico pregunta que cuánto `isSelected` le llege null, quiere cambiar el valor por `" "` , si no sabes cómo funciona los operadores ternarios, revisa la documentación, ya estás declarando las propiedades, al usar un operador ternario, alternas el valor de null por otro, en este caso `isSelected` al llegar null, puedes darle otro valor a tu criterio, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator, si no ves sentido la respuesta la puedes calificar como negativa

Comment: No estas contestando lo que te pregunte.. donde queres que OP escriba ese codigo? dentro de una propiedad? dentro del codigo que lee la propiedad? y si la propiedad la directamente el binding de un control wpf donde escribiria esto? tu codigo esta correcto.. no hay problema con eso... estoy tratando de entender a que apuntas con esta respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

No es buena idea estar cambiando el valor de una propiedad dependiendo de otro valor. Por convención las propiedades son para devolver y fijar valores. Tu problema es mejor gestionarlo desde un método.

```
public string Last4 { get; set; }
public string MY { get; set; }
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
public MopType CardIcon { get; set; }

public string SelectedString()
{
    return IsSelected ? "Seleccionado" : string.Empty
}
```

Te he puesto SelectedString en forma de método. Así solo tienes que preocuparte de gestionar el bool IsSelected, según como quieras manejarlo en tu aplicación.